Firebase App Distribution - Update vs Fresh Install
We are using Firebase App Distribution to send test APKs to our QA team, but one of the most common issues since the start of it is that it seems like the "current" app gets uninstalled and the new one is a fresh install, instead of just updating the app that is already there.
Although this doesn't cause us any major problems, it's a bit annoying having for example every time the need to login again.
I did some search but couldn't find anything related, is there something I can do to avoid that? Is there a configuration that I may have missed which will enable us having incremental updates and not fresh installs?

Do you use the same signing key or build within the same PC? If yes, the app should update issues of reinstall

We use GitHub CI/CD, so maybe that's the reason? GitHub uses a new dev key each time? I refer to the dev flavor we have created, not the production one which we use the same release signing key each time.

I use GitHub action too and don't experience that kind of issue. Could you share your workflow code here.
